# Incorporate AngularJS in an HTML File?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, inline

First off: The main goal of what I am trying to do, is to have only 1 HTML file. No separate javascript files.

I know that you can put javascript inline with HTML. But what I was wondering was if you can put AngularJS inline with HTML. Every time I try, it doesn't work as I want it to. So I am not sure it is even possible. Maybe there is something that I am missing. If there is, please tell me.

Right now, all that is in the Controller for the ng-app is an array. For the task, all I really need to do is loop through each element in the array. It is an array with a string, integer, integer, and another array inside. As of now, the only way I know to do this is through AngularJS. If there is a way without AngularJS, please tell me.

This is the javascript code. The html file basically just loops through each value in this array using ng-repeat.

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'xxx', max: 3, peak: 4, users: [{name: "name", ip: "127.0.0.1", date: "2014-05-19 06:45:28"}]}
    ];
}
```

Any help or workarounds are appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Please put some of your code. It doesn't seem you need AngularJs to do what you want. If it was the case, you may start by reading the doc and make some tutorials.

Comment: I have added the code snippet in my javascript. It isn't much code like I said. It is just an array. But I do not know how to loop through an array without using ng-repeat.

Comment: And what do you want to do ?
If your goal is to access those datas, you just need to put `{{items.name}}` `{{items.users.name}}` etc etc... in your html...

Comment: But you really don't need AngularJS to do that anyway...

Comment: I use the header:

<div class="container" ng-repeat="val in items">

to loop through each value in the array, then add them to a table on my webpage. I do not want to have a billion lines of html code, so I cannot just keep adding tables and what not. That's why in angular, it is easy to just use the ng-repeat tag.

Comment: So val will contain name, max, peak, users.name, users.ip...

Comment: Correct. It's basically saying "for(var val : items)"

Comment: Yes, so I don't get what's your problem ?

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to loop through all of the values without having a separate file for the controller/javascript. I want it all to be in one html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your angularJs App to be inside your Html file, just put everything you have in your js file inside `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`. 
And put it at the **end** of your file, just before `</html>`.

Comment: This worked. Before I was putting it at the top of the page in the <head></head> tags because I read in other places that worked for onclick events. I guess I needed it at the very bottom. Thanks a ton! The page does not run as smoothly as it would with an external file. But, none-the-less, it worked.